# Does two-sample chi-square test require equal sample sizes?

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size

I need to use two-sample chi-square test to compare two distributions and I am using R. I have read in multiple sources that the test does not require equality of sample sizes, yet this is the error I receive after running the test.

Please tell me if this is a requirement and if not, where in the function should I specify the sizes.

Here is the function definition in R:

```
    chisq.test(x, y = NULL, correct = TRUE,
       p = rep(1/length(x), length(x)), rescale.p = FALSE,
       simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
```

Comment: Can you post some illustration of your data?

Comment: It is just two independent vectors of numerical data with unspecified distributions, and with one's size about 6 times the other.